# I am getting TypeError: Cannot read property 'numberOfSuits' of undefined when I run the code below to post a new order on my firebase database

Tags: node.js, firebase, express

The code below returns a typeerror (TypeError: Cannot read property 'numberOfSuits' of undefined) on postman. Also, when i remove the last three fields to only post the first two fields, which are default, the data is written to the database, but I get an error in the console 'TypeError: res.json is not a function'

```
app.post('/order', (res, req) => {
    const newOrder = {
        orderCode: 'OOR-0006',
        status: 'In progress',
        numberOfSuits: req.body.numberOfSuits,
        neighborhood: req.body.neighborhood,
        houseDetails: req.body.houseDetails
    }
    db
    .collection('orders')
    .add(newOrder)
    .then(doc => {
        res.json({message: `New order ${newOrder.orderCode} created succesfully!`})
    }).catch(err => {
        console.error(err);
    });
});
```

Comment: `req.body` is undefined.  It's impossible for us to know why this is, given what you've shown here.  Please edit the question to show exactly what your client code is doing to invoke this route, and what you expect this function to do when it complete successfully.  We should be able to track everything from client to result given everything you show here.

Comment: Thank you @DougStevenson. By pointing out that 'req.body is undefined' I reevaluated the function and changed (res, req) to (req, res) and it worked.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I think changing

```
(res, req)
```

to

```
(req, res)
```

will fix the problem